# PHP/JS - Como exibir um alert() com o valor da $_SESSION

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Boa noite galera ! Precisava de uma ajuda com o **alert();** , estou querendo exibir na pagina **index.html**, um **alert();** mostrando que o dado foi inserido corretamente, lendo alguns posts no forum, deram a ideia de na pagina **index.php** *(onde é processado os dados)* salvar a mensagem em uma **$_SESSION** e puxar com **JS** la no **HTML** esse valor da **$_SESSION**. Testei a ideia e o resultado foi este:

**Codigo do PHP:**

```
$_SESSION['registro'] = "Seu gasto foi inserido corretamente!!";
header("location: index.html");
```

**Codigo no HTML**

```
<script>alert(".$_SESSION['registro'];.");</script>
```

*Lembrando que tentei mudar as "" para '', tanto da $_SESSION quanto do alert();*

**O resultado foi :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A duvida é ... Onde esta o erro? Caso não tenha erro que outra alternativa posso utilizar para mostrar esse alerta depois do insert feito pela index.php?

**[RESOLVIDO]**

Mudei meu **index.html** para **index.php** depois adicionei a seguinte linha de codigo :

```
<script>alert('<?php session_start();
 if($_SESSION['registro']!=null)
    {echo $_SESSION['registro'];}
 ?>');</script>
```

*Importante frisar que eu não estava colocando o **session_start();***

E na minha pagina de carregamento de dados adicionei o valor do **$_SESSION**

```
session_start();
           if($_SESSION['registro'] == null){
                $_SESSION['registro'] = "Registro cadastro com sucesso !";
           }

           header("location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não obtive total conhecimento em relação a PHP, mas, com o tanto que aprendi, posso dizer que o problema está exatamente no fato de você estar tentando pegar o valor em um arquivo HTML, o qual não "pode" acessar os "objetos" do PHP. Portanto, você teria que transformar esse arquivo HTML em PHP, e no caso, acho que você poderia fazer assim:

```
<script>alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['registro']; ?>");</script>
```

**[Editado]**

Como agora você está trabalhando com dois arquivos PHP, em que um atribui o valor, e o outro acessa o valor, você deverá usar o `session_start()` em ambos, e no que acessa o valor, você deverá fazer assim:

```
<script>
    alert("<?php echo isset($_SESSION['registro'])?$_SESSION['registro']:null; ?>");
</script>
```

Ou seja, se o `$_SESSION['registro']` existe, ele coloca o valor dele, senão, o valor será `null`.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Fala gustavo !! Fiz o teste e mesmo assim não funcionou, mesmo mudando a extensão para PHP e adicionando o codigo php

Comment: Você está usando um servidor pessoal ou você está hospedando a página na web? Seja qual for, há suporte a PHP, correto?

Comment: Estou utilizando o xampp para usar em localhost

Comment: Qual o valor que está saindo?

Comment: Não está saindo valor nenhum (imprimindo nada na tela), fiz o teste na mesma pagina, e deu certo, porem, não consigo utilizar o header para ir para a pagina inicial, pois se eu usar ele o alert não chega a aparecer (visivelmente)

Comment: Eu adicionei mais informações à resposta

Comment: Obrigado !! deu certo Gustavo !!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['registro'])) { ?>
    <script>alert('<?= $_SESSION['registro'] ?>');</script>
<?php } ?>
```